# Using a creative commons image in a video

Tags: copyright

I will create a video and publish it on YouTube. A segment of the video is a voice-over slideshow-like sequence of images. (I will zoom some images, also some "slides" may be a combination of multiple images.) Some of these images are under a CC-BY-SA license.

Is such video a derivative work of the images? If the answer is yes, then how one could include images in a video without making it a derivative work?

Note: It seems that any inclusion of music in a video makes the video a derivative work of the music. But for images, I couldn't find what the consensus is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is such video a derivate work of the images?

Yes.

> If the answer is yes, then how one could include images in a video without making it a derivate work?

You can't. At least not if the images are distributed under a CC-licence. Even if it's just one image (or song), you have to follow the ShareAlike clause. Also, if you use multiple works by other artists (regardless of what it is, i.e. images, songs, video snippets ...) that are licenced under different CC licences that include the ShareAlike clause, you can't publish your video at all without violating the licencing terms of at least one of those works. See [the remix chart here](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-combine-material-under-different-creative-commons-licenses-in-my-work) for more information on how material licenced under different licences can be used together for derivate works.